# Saml2 With Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

I want to be able to integrate SAML2 with an existing ASP.Net without an IdP. Im currently looking into using Sustainsys. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application to be the SP then yes.

"The Sustainsys.Saml2 library adds SAML2P support to ASP.NET web sites, allowing the web site to act as a SAML2 Service Provider (SP)".

However, to function it needs a SAML IDP.

So although you have an SP, you can't do much with it until you have an IDP to connect to.